# IBM JSON4J ClassNotFound when running unit test

Tags: json, maven, unit-testing, websphere-liberty, json4j

I am developing a basic servlet deployed on WebSphere Liberty. This servlet uses a custom class I wrote to perform its business logic.

I tried to write some unit tests for this custom class which I can run using maven. But when I launch `maven test`, some tests fail with the following exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/ibm/json/java/internal/SerializerVerbose
at com.ibm.utils.JMAuthorizationModule.processPostRequest(JMAuthorizationModule.java:78)
at com.ibm.test.JMAuthorizationModuleTest.shouldNotAcceptToCreateASkillForADifferentUser(JMAuthorizationModuleTest.java:42)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.json.java.internal.SerializerVerbose
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 32 more
```

The class that I intend to test uses the IBM Library JSON4J. The class can run without any problem when my servlet is deployed inside the Liberty runtime, but apparently the JSON4J is not found by maven when the tests are run.

Could you please explain what I should configure so that the ClassNotFound is not thrown when running my tests?

I also attach my pom.xml in case it may help:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>maven online</id>
        <name>maven repository</name>
        <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>liberty maven online</id>
        <name>liberty maven repository</name>
        <url>http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/websphere/wasdev/maven/repository/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.ibm.jm.tests</groupId>
<artifactId>TestSecurityGateway</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>Test</name>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.tools.target</groupId>
        <artifactId>was-liberty</artifactId>
        <version>LATEST</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    <warName>JMTestApp</warName>
                    <outputDirectory>bluemix/apps</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Thanks

Comment: Don't use proprietorially rebranded `JSON4J`. Use `JSON4J` from `Apache Wink` instead — https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.wink/wink-json4j.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I ended up doing.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use the one that'd be used at runtime?  Plus, WInk is not exactly a vibrant project.

Comment: Do you know the correct maven dependency to include for the IBM JSON4J lib. All the ones I tested with were giving a ClassNotFoundException since the com.ibm.json.java.internal package was missing from the jar.

Comment: @covener Which one and why, whichever it is, it should be used during **unit testing**? If you mean something that contains `com.ibm.json.java` packages, is it even available in public Maven repository? As for "not vibrant", I really don't understand how this applies here. Did `WAS` stopped using `Apache Wink` codebase?

Comment: @JohanMereaux If you find the solution reasonable, I can expand my comment into an answer. With more details and rationale.

Comment: @fnt In the end, i rewrote everything with apache wink and got my unit tests working. So I guess i can consider your solution reasonable, even tough I don't really understand why the maven repo for Liberty libs does not provide the same libs that are present at runtime in Liberty

Comment: IBM's version of JSON4J sorts the property names, so if your tests don't care about that aspect, then the Wink version is usable.